# HTTP Status 500 - php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server

Tags: php, tomcat

the following error occurred when i tried to run a php file through apache tomcat 8.5 i have tried the method from this link http://www.jvmhost.com/articles/run-php-applications-in-tomcat-7-with-php-java-bridge at last and tried many other processes but it remains unsolved please help me to get rid of this problem thank you. and the error is the following:

```
HTTP Status 500 - php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server

type Exception report

message php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.init(FastCGIServlet.java:133)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server
    php.java.bridge.http.NPChannelFactory.test(NPChannelFactory.java:64)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.init(FastCGIServlet.java:131)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

java.io.IOException: File \\.\pipe\C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\temp\JavaBridge4557505765763204955.socket not writable
    php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException.<init>(FCGIConnectException.java:37)
    php.java.bridge.http.NPChannelFactory.test(NPChannelFactory.java:64)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.init(FastCGIServlet.java:131)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

java.io.IOException: PHP not found. Please install php-cgi. PHP test command was: [php-cgi, -v] 
    php.java.bridge.Util$Process.start(Util.java:1145)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FCGIProcess.start(FCGIProcess.java:68)
    php.java.bridge.http.NPChannelFactory.doBind(NPChannelFactory.java:94)
    php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionFactory.runFcgi(FCGIConnectionFactory.java:88)
    php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionFactory$1.run(FCGIConnectionFactory.java:109)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.5.4 logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
```

Comment: I copy/pasted the code exactly as it is, and it's working fine for me. What do you get when you enter `http://localhost:9000/php/gethint.php?q=a` directly in your browser's address bar? Any errors?

Comment: yeah the error is following:
HTTP Status 500 - php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server

Comment: Well, that is obviously a server problem. I have no clue how to solve that, sorry. If you replace all your code with a simple PHP script such as `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` and enter the address directly, do you get the same result? If so, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38945490/edit) and remove all that code since it is not relevant - and add your `HTTP Status 500` error to it.

Comment: Thank you for your Suggestion.

Comment: You problems seems like a permission issue. I would recommend moving your tomcat server outside the Program Files folder. The underlying error is pretty straight forward: `java.io.IOException: File \\.\pipe\C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\temp\JavaBridge4557505765763204955.socket not writable` Or you could give full access permission to the apache folder and its contents.

Comment: i have changed the permission to full access for user but the problem is still on.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message:

> PHP not found. Please install php-cgi. PHP test command was: [php-cgi, -v]

It is all you need...